# Sort by Name first then number in sql query from a delimited string

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, sql-like

We have designed to register customer's station-division records in 1 field. So the table rows looks like this.

```
create table test4 (f2 varchar(100))

insert into test4 (f2) values ('A08-0100')
insert into test4 (f2) values ('006-0100')
insert into test4 (f2) values ('008-0200')
insert into test4 (f2) values ('008-0200')
insert into test4 (f2) values ('007-0100')
insert into test4 (f2) values ('009-0100')
insert into test4 (f2) values ('009-F100')
```

Now I want to sort it by station, then division, but I want the letters to be displayed first on the first group.

What I've tried so far is

```
select * from test4 order by left(f2, 3), right(f2, 40)

First Group(station)        2nd Group (division)
A08                  -      0100
```

Expected output:

```
A08-0100
006-0100
007-0100
008-0200
008-0200
009-0100
009-F100
```

Comment: Please show example results.  What does "first group" mean?  Alpha in station? Or alpha in division? or alpha in either?  Does that mean separate groups for different alpha-s?  Will alpha always be in 1st position of station or division, or could it be in any/or/many positions?  Need more refined requirements.

Comment: when you mention letter to be displayed first couldn't understand the part as you want sorting based on some left and right of the string. If you could display your expected results that would be helpful

Comment: hi guys, i updated the question, thank's for checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the station starts with a letter and sort it accordingly... something like this:

```
case when left(f2, 1) like '[a-z]%' then 1 else 2 end
```

Use this in the order by clause, like so:

```
select * from test4 order by case when left(f2, 1) like '[a-z]%' then 1 else 2 end, left(f2, 3), right(f2, 4);
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4a4ff/4) here.